# C2661 when using std::make_unique

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have an error when I am trying to use std::make_unique. I probably have made a very simple mistake and I would be thankful if someone pointed it out. I am using GLAD and GLFW as 3rd party libraries. I get an error code of C2661 when I run it, C2661  'Window::Window': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments on the next code snippet in window.cpp.

```
return std::make_unique<Window>(std::move(nativeWindow), width, height);
```

```
Window.hpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

struct Window final {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Window> createWindow(int width, int height, std::string title);

    bool shouldClose() { return glfwWindowShouldClose(nativeWindow); }

    void swapBuffers() { glfwSwapBuffers(nativeWindow); }
private:
    GLFWwindow* nativeWindow;
    int width;
    int height;
    std::string title;
};

Window.cpp
#include "Window.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<Window> Window::createWindow(int width, int height, std::string title) {
    nativeWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(nativeWindow);

    return std::make_unique<Window>(std::move(nativeWindow), width, height);
}
```

sorry for bad code quality.

Comment: Whats the compiler error?

Comment: I get a C2661 error. I am using visual studio 2022.

Comment: Thats not the full error message.

Comment: sorry it throws, C2661 'Window::Window': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Still not the full error message. Please add the __full__ error message the compiler prints to the question.

Comment: like just copy and paste exactly what the complier give, most of the error is just the file where it happened

Comment: @Cake Why are you creating `std::unique_ptr<Window>`s instead of just `Window`s objects? `Window` is not polymorphic, inheriting from anything and it's also `final` so why create `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: Not sure, I are fairly new to c++, only about a year, and am not too familiar with all of its features and best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Window` class does not have a constructor taking `GLFWwindow*, int, int` as would be required for this:

```cpp
return std::make_unique<Window>(std::move(nativeWindow), width, height);
```

However, it seems you are encapsulating the wrong thing.

- If a `Window` instance is copied or moved, there will suddenly be *two* owners of the `GLFWwindow`, with a double `free` later likely.
- When a `Window` is destroyed, you don't call `glfwDestroyWindow` to free the resource, which will leak.

Read [The rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

What you *should* be doing is really to store a `unique_ptr<GLFWwindow>` in `Window` to make the problems mentioned above go away without having to implement the manual resource management mentioned in *The rule of 3/5/0*.

Example:

```cpp
struct Window final {
public:
    Window(int width, int height, std::string title);

    inline bool shouldClose() { return glfwWindowShouldClose(nativeWindow.get()); }
    inline void swapBuffers() { glfwSwapBuffers(nativeWindow.get()); }

private:
    struct glfwWindowDestroyer {
        void operator()(GLFWwindow* win) const {
            glfwDestroyWindow(win);
        }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, glfwWindowDestroyer> nativeWindow;
    int width;
    int height;
    std::string title;
};
```

The constructor implementation would then be:

```
Window::Window(int width, int height, std::string title) :
    nativeWindow(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr)),
    width(width),
    height(height),
    title(std::move(title))
{
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(nativeWindow.get());
}
```

That way the `createWindow` function (which should have been `static`) can be removed. Just create `Window`s like normal C++ objects. `Window` objects are now safely moveable (and non-copyable) without any extra tinkering.

---

If you for some reason still would like to have a helper function to create `unique_ptr<Window>`s, you can, but as you will see, it will be rather pointless:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Window>
Window::createWindow(int width, int height, std::string title) {
    return std::make_unique<Window>(width, height, title);
}
```

There's not much of a gain to call `Window::createWindow` instead of just calling `std::make_unique<Window>` directly. Also, the use of `unique_ptr<Window>`s is dubious. `Window` is `final` and it's not inheriting from anything. You should probably just store `Window`s directly in a container.

Comment: upvote for "unique_ptr actually not needed"

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```cpp
std::make_unique<Window>(std::move(nativeWindow), width, height);
```

assumes your Window type has the following constructor available:

```cpp
Window::Window(GLFWwindow* win, int width, int height)
```

This can be fixed by adding the correct constructor (I've also passed through the title, which you weren't storing anywhere).

Window.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

struct Window final {
public:


    // constructor for Window object
    Window(GLFWwindow* win, int w, int h, std::string title) 
       : nativeWindow(win), width(w), height(h), title(title)
    {
    }

    // I assume you meant for this method to be static?
    // It makes very little (if any sense) as a member function.
    static 
    std::unique_ptr<Window> createWindow(int width, int height, std::string title);

    bool shouldClose() { return glfwWindowShouldClose(nativeWindow); }

    void swapBuffers() { glfwSwapBuffers(nativeWindow); }
   


private:
    GLFWwindow* nativeWindow;
    int width;
    int height;
    std::string title;
};
```

```cpp
#include "Window.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<Window> Window::createWindow(int width, int height, std::string title) {
    nativeWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(nativeWindow);

    return std::make_unique<Window>(nativeWindow, width, height, title);
}
```

Then you should be call the method like so:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Window> ptr = Window::createWindow(640, 480, "hello")
```